# Android: images uploaded to API loses exif data(Equipment Make)

Tags: android, exif

I have created a web API project. One of the endpoint receives the image and reads the exif data. This works well when the image is uploaded from an iPhone. When the same API is used using Android devices, few images lose "Equipment Make" tag. I have checked and the image uploaded doesn't have that tag. What I need to know is if there is any chance the device is erasing the same tag(Equipment Make)? Any OS issue? I just want to confirm if there is any chance the device is messing things up(mostly Lenovo and Xiaomi)? The Android developers are sure they are sending image with that tag.

Comment: Some cameras dont write EXIF data. How you are uploading the images?

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos the problem is I don't know anything about client app. I am only concerned with the backend stuff. We never had this issue with iOS devices. Its few images from Android devices that do not have this particular tag. But the developers say they do have this tag.

Answer (score 0):

Some phones do a poor job of writing the Exif data. The Android developers can write some Exif data for the image themselves though to ensure that it is there.